# How to insert new key value pair into fetch database object in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object

I am developing application in rails 4 where i have to insert new key value pair after fetch record and response back.

I fetch 10 records and its loop every record look like below:

```
#<User id: 29, email: "two@gmail.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$Ty2NOaVCsAK6sQwdQJHMgen9/fNkeDb.TmYY5Xyk/M5i...", fname: "bondalu2", lname: "two", created_at: "2014-08-22 06:09:46", updated_at: "2014-08-22 22:14:21", username: "bondalutwo", dob: "1950-01-01", zip: "32658", status: 1, image_id: 14, pref_age_low: 18, pref_age_high: 18, pref_radius: 5, pref_zip: 32658, token: "289c9d805697fa5dbec705c9574a7e2d">
```

How to insert `new key "profile_img" and its value "abc.jpg" (diff for every user)` into above every object of users.

```
Like: #<User id: 29, email: "two@gmail.com", profile_img: "abc.jpg", password_digest:"...
```

I tried but not getting. How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your User table have a column called 'profile_img'? 
From the above code it seems that it doesn't have it. So, firstly you need to add a migration to add a 'profile_img' column to your User table.

After that you can do this :

```
 value = 'Some Value'
    @users.each{|user| user.update_attributes(:profile_img => value)}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i dont want to add it into DB. Without it i need to do.

Comment: Try and use this gem called mini_record https://github.com/DAddYE/mini_record.  It allows you to alter your  table in the model itself without migrations.

Comment: add methods using attr_accessor and then get and set values for it as needed.